# Adding tags to photos in the Gallery

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, gallery

The Gallery has an option to group photos by "People" and "Tags".  Does anyone know how to set these tags?  There doesn't appear to be a feature to tag photos taken with the phone's camera, and I've tried copying an existing tagged photo onto the phone (both via MTP and email) and the tags were ignored.

Answer (score 5):

You need to have a Picasa account (which is auto-created if you have a Google+ account) and also have **Sync Google Photos** turned on (which is automatically on if you have Google Sync turned on.)

Share your photo with Picasa.

Go to **Picasa Web Albums** at https://picasaweb.google.com/home and find your photo.

In the right-hand margin, you'll see **Tags**  and a "+" button with a Tag icon.

Click that button, which is the Add Tags button.

Enter your tags, which are space separated.

On your Android device, go into **Gallery** and go up to the top level using the Up caret in the upper left, which is the left-most side of the action bar.

It should refresh automatically.  If not, you can manually choose "Refresh" in the menu in the upper right.  This is what syncs the tags that you created on the web to your Android device.  (Sync Google Photos is what really does it under the covers.)

Now you can choose the album that has the photo that you tagged above.

Then choose the menu item **Group by** > **Tags**.

Voila!  You can now see your photos grouped by tag.

Happy tagging!

Picasa Web tagging is documented at:
http://support.google.com/picasa/bin/answer.py?answer=55851

Sync Google Photos is documented at: http://support.google.com/mobile/bin/answer.py?answer=2395276

Comment: I suspect this is probably going to be the best answer, but as far as I can see there are a couple of minor snags with this approach:

You end up with two copies of each photo: one in the "Camera" album and another in the Picasa-synced album.  The tags are only applied to the latter.

Adding People tags in Picasa causes the whole album to be shared with those people, and that might not be what you want.

Comment: @mavit: I'd say there are actually also some major drawbacks here. The solution to go via Picasa is useless if you are offline or in a location where Picasa is not reachable for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

use [quick pick](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alensw.PicFolder&hl=en) or [f-stop](http://www.fstopapp.com/) or [any other gallery manager apps](http://lifehacker.com/5814868/the-best-photo-management-app-for-android)

Answer (score 0):

concerning the people tags,you can manually tag unrecognised faces by tapping and holding on said face,at least in the Samsung galaxy's gallery (which possibly isn't stock android)

Answer (score -2):

Touch in the date area. That show tags and permits to add and edit them